# sed special character replace not working in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, special-characters

I want to write a script 'test.sh' that will take a user's input and replace all special characters with a '\' + the character.  My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'input='"$1"
arg=`echo "$1" | sed 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\/]:\\&:g'`
echo 'modified input='"$arg"
```

My command works on the string 'xy', which does not have any special characters. I run this in my terminal:

```
test.sh xy
```

And I obtain:

```
input=xy
modified input=xy
```

However, when I run this:

```
test.sh x.y
```

I get:

```
input=x.y
modified input=x&y
```

I don't understand why this script is not working.  I expect to get:

```
input=x.y
modified input=x\.y
```

I think the problem lies in this sed command but I'm not sure where:

```
sed 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\/]:\\&:g'
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are capturing the group right. Try this?

`sed 's:\([]\[\^\$\.\*\/]\):\\\1:g'`

Edit: nevermind, I wasn't aware of the relevance of &. The problem is you need to extra escape the slashes in replacement because of the parsing and passing to sub shell.

`sed 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\/]:\\\\&:g'`

Also, if you used $(command) instead of backticks, you don't need the extra \'s

Comment: Yes, if I add two more '\' as you did will work. But I don't see why they are needed. Is there a reference you can point me to understand this? Also, not sure what you mean regarding $(command)

Comment: enclosing commands in backticks uses simple substitution - so the the command is parsed by the current shell. `$(command)` opens a subshell, so anything inside the parens runs as if on its own command line. See for more info: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

Answer (score 1):

So the task is to write a `sed` substitution that escapes all special characters (defined as the characters `[]^$.*/`, and I added `\` too) in a string.

The substitution might look like

```
s/[][\^$.*/]/\\&/g
```

Note that we don't really have to escape any of the characters in the `[...]` set (the `\` is treated literally too, so we *can't* escape anything in there), and that the only thing we have to make sure of is that `]` is in the very beginning of it.

So the script (rewritten as a shell function, and revamped in other ways) becomes

```
function escape
{
    printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's/[][\^$.*/]/\\&/g'
}
```

Testing:

```
$ escape 'hello world'
hello world

$  escape '*.*'
\*\.\* 

$ escape '\/'
\\\/

$ escape '/\'
\/\\

$ escape 's/[][\^$.*/]/\\&/g'
s\/\[\]\[\\\^\$\.\*\/\]\/\\\\&\/g
```